# Limit of sequence and Riemann sum problem work verification

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{n}{k^2-4n^2}}}$$ My attempt: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{n}{k^2-4n^2}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\frac{k^2}{n^2}-4}}} = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\right) \cdot \int_0^1{\frac{1}{x^2-4}} = 0 \cdot \left(-\frac{\log(3)}{4}\right) =0$$

Am I right?

Comment: Some mistakes: It should be $\frac{1}{n^2}\times n$ in the second expression and no $\lim 1/n^2$ in $\lim \frac{1}{n^2}\int $. This changes the final result.

Comment: I added brackets. Is it still incorrect?

Comment: Yes: $\frac{n}{k^2-4n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{(k/n)^2-4}$ not $\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(k/n)^2-4}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{k^2-4n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2\left(\frac{k^2}{n^2}-4\right)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{k^2}{n^2}-4\right)}$$

So

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{k^2-4n^2}= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2-4}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{-\ln(3)}{4} $$

I hope I make no mistake !